# Block registration by URL referrer?

Tags: urls, spam

Is it possible to block user registration based on the referring URL?  I have an open registration WP site (configured so users can post ads and events) and while I typically don't get a lot of spam registrations (there is a reCaptcha involved), I was listed on a site as an example of the capabilities of the theme I'm using, and it generates a lot of "test" type of traffic.  I like the traffic, but I don't like people registering just to post false test posts just to see how the site works, so I'd ultimately like to simply block registration from that referring URL.  Thanks!

Comment: do these spam registrations really have referrer infos?

Comment: Yes they do, because technically they're not spam.  I am listed on the main developer's site as an "example" on how someone can customize the site (mine is quite customized), so I'm listed on the "Showcase".  These people come to my site, and instead of just looking, they feel the need to register and post test ads on the site.  I want to disable the registration process for them, but not block them from viewing the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `"register_post"` hook that happens just before the user is saved to the database 
or you can use `"register_form"` hook and check the referring URL for a match and die();

Comment: ...or hook a function on the [`wpmu_active_signup`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-signup.php#L385) filter: `if(strpos($_REQUEST['HTTP_REFERER'], 'evil-site.com') !== false) return 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

Along with what Bainternet said, you could also set a session with that url in it, so if they go to your site and then go to another site/page and come back. You would still have that referring url there to check for.